# How can i add class to link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here i am trying to add the class for `link_to` element in rails.

here i have link_to element, i have added class for this element. but i am getting error..

here is what i have done

```
<%= link_to '+ Add New Product', :class => 'btn btn-primary', {action:"new_product_list_path"} %>
```

error i am getting is

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...tion:"new_product_list_path"} );@output_buffer.to_s ... ^ 
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' 
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct version:

```
<%= link_to '+ Add New Product', new_product_list_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```